# Python/OpenCV convert cv to cv2

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I have a python script that I wrote using OpenCV and am in the process of updating everything to OpenCV2 (cv2). The issue is when I use PIL to convert the image into a CVarray.

```
pil_im = pil_im.convert('L')
    cv_im = cv.CreateImageHeader(pil_im.size, cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1)
    cv.SetData(cv_im, pil_im.tostring(), pil_im.size[0])
```

`pil_im` is found later in my code,

```
# Crop images
        for img in imgList:
            pil_im = Image.open(img)
            cv_im = pil2cvGrey(pil_im)
            faces = DetectFace(cv_im, faceCascade)
            if faces:
                n = 1
                for face in faces:
                    croppedImage = imgCrop(pil_im, face[0], padding)
                    (fname, ext) = os.path.splitext(img)
                    fname = os.path.basename(fname)
                    croppedImage.save(outputimg + '\\' + fname + ' -c' + ext)
                    n += 1
```

I know that my code works as it should I just am trying to make the pyinstaller exe smaller by only includeing CV2, currently including CV and CV2.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know cv2 does not use the CVarray types any more. These are wrappers of the c datatypes, instead cv2 now natively uses numpy data structures. To convert from a PIL image to a cv2 array do

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy

img = Image.open('lena.png')
array = numpy.array( img )
```